# Why can I assign a string to a pointer to float?

Tags: c, pointers, typing

Why is the code below working? Should that be a compilation error (or at least a run-time error)?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
        float *buf = "happy holiday";        // notice the float
        printf("content of buf = %s\n",buf); //its working
        return 0;
}
```

I compiled it and got just a warning:

```
~/Desktop/cTest>gcc -o run run.c
run.c: In function `main':
run.c:4: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always compile with `-Wall -Werror -Wextra` (at a minimum).  Then you get this:

```
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:4: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
test.c:5: warning: format '%s' expects type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'float *'
test.c: At top level:
test.c:3: warning: unused parameter 'argc'
test.c:3: warning: unused parameter 'argv'
```

It "works" because in practice, there's no difference between a `char *` and a `float *` under the hood on your platform.  Your code is really no different to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
        float *buf = (float *)"happy holiday";
        printf("content of buf = %s\n",(char *)buf);
        return 0;
}
```

This is well-defined behaviour, unless the alignment requirements of `float` and `char` differ, in which case it results in undefined behaviour (see C99, 6.3.2.3 p7).

Comment: I disagree with your claim that at minimum one should use those warning options. Even in this tiny example, you've produced false positives (the unused parameter warnings) which usually *cannot* be suppressed without adding useless code. Here the other form of `main` could be used, but what if you needed just `argv` but not `argc`? I'm a big proponent of making the compiler warn (and error out) on invalid or definitively-bad-style code, but the set of options you suggested will necessarily reject perfectly good code unless you make an effort to uglify it for gcc's sake...

Comment: @R.. I can live with the trivial fixes to deal with the "false" positives in exchange for the protection it affords. What are you advocating instead?

Comment: I typically use `-Wall` (but not `-Wextra`) and then individually turn off some options with `-Wno-*` (e.g. unused function parameters).

Answer (score 1):

This program is not strictly conforming, a compiler is required to output a diagnostic and has  the right to refuse to compile it. So don't do it.

Comment: @NiklasB. it violates the constraints of the assignment operator: not strictly conforming. See C99, 6.5.16.1p1

Answer (score 1):

This is an unfortunate behavior of `gcc`, and if somebody could get it fixed, we'd all be dealing with a lot less buggy software. Unfortunately there's a lack of will to fix many things like this. Submitting a bug report would not hurt.

Comment: Why is it a bug?  The standard requires the compiler to issue a diagnostic, and it does.

Comment: Indeed, I missed that it was technically meeting the requirements of the standard by printing a warning. Personally I believe the compiler should reject programs with constraints violations like this, especially when there's no correct/legitimate use for the construct.

Comment: `gcc` is very permissive for compatibility reasons with old programs, but I also find it too permissive in a lot of occasions.